# I am losing my definition of a form controller when the controller is set in an ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs

I have code that uses AngularJS v1.5.0 and creates multiple forms with an ng-repeat like this. Note that inside the form I show the form details between xx and xx:

```
<div ng-click="wos.wordFormRowClicked(wf)"
     ng-form="wos.wordFormNgForm_{{wf.wordFormId}}"
     ng-repeat="wf in wos.word.wordForms">

     xx {{ wos['wordFormNgForm_1465657579'] }}  xx
```

When the runs I am able to see the form details appear between the xx and xx and I am able to query the state of the form like this:

```
wordFormCheckAndUpdate = (): ng.IPromise<any> => {
    var self = this;
    var wordFormNgForm = 'wordFormNgForm_' + wf.wordFormId;
    self[wordFormNgForm].$setDirty();
```

However in my code after calling this procedure the form becomes undefined and also nothing shows between the xx and xx. As I step through this procedure with the debugger the last line I see is the line setting the value of a and then as soon as the function finishes the information between the xx and xx disappears and the form becomes undefined:

```
wordEditSubmit = (): ng.IPromise<any> => {
    var self = this;
    return this.wordFormCheckAndUpdate().then(
        () => {
            return self.$http({
                url: self.ac.dataServer + "/api/word/Put",
                method: "PUT",
                data: self.word
            })
                .then(
                (response: ng.IHttpPromiseCallbackArg<IWordRow>): any => {
                    self.word = angular.copy(response.data);
                    self['wordNgForm'].$setPristine();
                    self.uts.remove(self.words, 'wordId', self.word.wordId);
                    response.data.current = true;
                    self.words.push(response.data);
                    var a = 99;
                },
                (error: ng.IHttpPromiseCallbackArg<any>): any => {
                    self.ers.error(error);
                    return self.$q.reject(error);
                });
        }
    );
}
```

My problem is that if I then try to repeat this:

```
setDirty = (): ng.IPromise<any> => {
    var self = this;
    var wordFormNgForm = 'wordFormNgForm_' + wf.wordFormId;
    self[wordFormNgForm].$setDirty();
}
```

then the controller object `self[wordFormNgForm]` is no longer defined.

For reference.  Here is how new wordForms are created:

```
wordFormAdd = () => {
    this.wordFormId = Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000);
    var emptyWordForm: IWordForm = <IWordForm>{
        wordId: this.word.wordId,
        wordFormId: this.wordFormId,
        posId: 1,
        statusId: Status.New
    };
    this.word.wordForms.push(emptyWordForm);
    this.wordNgForm.$setDirty();
}
```

Here is the remove function:

```
remove = (arr, property, num) => {
    arr.forEach((elem, index) => {
        if (elem[property] === num)
            arr.splice(index, 1);
    })
};
```

Does anyone have any advice as to how I could solve this problem

Comment: Have you tried google first? What exactly is not working?

Comment: Please add the code where `wordFormCheckAndUpdate` is called. I'm suspecting a wrong scope here.

Comment: Could you provide a fiddle for this problem? I would love to help if I can try solutions directly on the code.

Comment: "var self" will create the variable "self" everytime by deleting it from memory stack. so the objects bind to it will not exists. :)

Comment: All objects exist with the exception of the form controller.

Comment: wordFormCheckUpdate in the question has been replaced with setDirty() which is a simpler method that still gives the same problem.

Comment: @Alan, You've added most of the relevant parts of your code to the post. But, can you create a [plunker](https://plnkr.co) or a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) that could reproduce your problem?

Answer (score 3):

Your problem could have been explained well with a demo reproducing the issue. Nevertheless, I've partially reproduced your problem [***in a fiddle here***](https://jsfiddle.net/baktash93/ddk1akzh/) (*not with Typescript though, it's just vanilla JS*).

What I suspect happens when you first add a `wordForm` object with the `wordFormAdd()` method, is that, if you try to reference the `FormController` object associated with the `ng-form` in the same method immediately, then it might be too early to do so, because the `$digest` loop might not have been completed.

This is because as soon as you click and trigger the `wordFormAdd()` function, a new `emptyWordForm` object is added to the `word.wordForms` array and immediately `ng-repeated` in your view. But, *the controller hasn't had enough time to associate the newly created `ng-form` object with itself*, so you may end up with referencing an *undefined* object.

```
wordFormAdd = () => {
this.wordFormId = Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000);
    var emptyWordForm: IWordForm = <IWordForm>{
        wordId: this.word.wordId,
        wordFormId: this.wordFormId,
        posId: 1,
        statusId: Status.New
    };
    this.word.wordForms.push(emptyWordForm);
    this.wordNgForm.$setDirty();  //<== too early to do so
}
```

To overcome this, you should wrap that portion of the code within a `$timeout` wrapper. This ensures that Angular's so-called *dirty check* (or simply the digest loop) is finished.

Also note that keeping a single `wordNgForm` or `wordFormId` reference doesn't make sense, because you might dynamically add other forms, each of which may be associated with a *new* `wordNgForm` key and `wordFormId`.

I would suggest doing the above like so:

```
wordFormAdd = () => {
    this.wordFormId = Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000);
    ...
    this.word.wordForms.push(emptyWordForm);

    this._timeout(function(){ // $timeout injected and assigned to this._timeout in controller definition
        var wordFormNgForm = 'wordFormNgForm_' + this.wordFormId;
        this[wordFormNgForm].$setDirty();  // <==
    });
}
```

---

> However in my code after calling this procedure the form becomes `undefined` and also *nothing shows between the xx and xx*. As I step through this procedure with the debugger the last line I see is the line setting the value of `a` and then as soon as the function finishes the information between the xx and xx disappears and the form becomes `undefined`:

A possible reason where the *watched* value in your view (`{{ wos['wordFormNgForm_1465657579'] }}`) becomes `undefined`, is that you are fetching new values and storing a copy of them in the controller's `self.word` property:

```
...
.then((response: ng.IHttpPromiseCallbackArg<IWordRow>): any => {
    self.word = angular.copy(response.data);   // <==
    ...
},
```

By doing so, the collection under `word.wordForms` that was previously *`ng-repeat`ed* in the view is *changed* and the watched value is no longer a valid reference to an item of this collection.

Meanwhile, `self['wordNgForm']` in the `wordEditSubmit` certainly isn't associated with a `FormController` object as far as the `ng-repeat` in your view is concerned. This is because the `FormController` object keys associated with an `ng-form` must have a format (*as imposed by you*) similar to something like `wordFormNgForm_1465657579`. Therefore, here too, you are referencing an *undefined* property under `self['wordNgForm']`:

```
...
.then((response: ng.IHttpPromiseCallbackArg<IWordRow>): any => {
    self.word = angular.copy(response.data);
    self['wordNgForm'].$setPristine();  // <== 
    ...
},
```

Comment: Thanks for all of your suggestions. Just one thing. Can you please explain what this is doing: this._timeout(function(){ // $timeout injected and assigned to this._timeout in controller definition
        var wordFormNgForm = 'wordFormNgForm_' + this.wordFormId;
        this[wordFormNgForm].$setDirty();  // <==
    });   If I have a timeout then don't I have to set a time interval?

Comment: You could add a time delay, but don't need to. By this, you are roughly mimicking JavaScript's native `setTimeout(fn, 0)` behavior where the delay is `0`. But, in AngularJS, this is different. Such that, anything that is wrapped in a `$timeout` is executed after AngularJS has completed one digest cycle. The thing is that you don't know exactly how long would it take for the digest cycle to complete. Therefore, AngularJS will evaluate your code whenever the cycle is complete by executing your code in _at least_ `0` seconds.

Comment: This is also equivalent to doing something like: `$timeout(someOperation, 0)`

Answer (score 0):

This looks like standard issue with java script that `this` means different things depending what called the function. 
What I would advise is to generate form names and place them in `wos.word.wordForms` collection and bind them from there. Doing gymnastics like `ng-form="wos.wordFormNgForm_{{wf.wordFormId}}"` and `var wordFormNgForm = 'wordFormNgForm_' + wf.wordFormId;` feel quite awkward.
If there is a reason you are not using this approach please tell me, there might be a different solution :)

Comment: The self and the this object show everything else but the one thing that is undefined is the controller.  Also it is defined before getting a new copy of word and not after.  So not related to self / this. Also have around 1,000 references to self / this in other parts of the code and have used it extensively in every method

Comment: I am creating the forms inside the ng-repeat as my code allows new wordForms to be created or deleted by pressing a button. So the number of wordForms can change.

Comment: When I create a new wordForm I give it a unique Id using the method that I added to the question.  This seems to work fine except as mentioned later on after getting new words it no longer is defined.